# Rails 5 - rendering array defined in application_helper.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, view, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to use [nhl_scores](https://github.com/tbloncar/nhl_scores) gem to get and display recent NHL game scores on the page. This is how I defined the method in app/helpers/application_helper.rb:

```
def scores
    games = NHLScores::Games.new
    s = []
    games.recent.each do |g|
        s.push("#{g.away_team} @ #{g.home_team} - #{g.away_team_score}:#{g.home_team_score}")
    end
    s
end
```

And this is how I display this array:

```
<ul>
    <%= scores.each do |s| %>
        <li><%= s %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

The result is:

[pic with result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEqEp.png)

Yeah, for some reason the full array gets displayed after the last closing li tag but before the closing ul tag. How do I remove it? Should I define the method that returns this array elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<ul>
    <% scores.each do |s| %>
        <li><%= s %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

The `<%= %>` is displaying the entire scores array again which you dont want(`<%= %>` causes the value to be displayed).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `<%=` to output the result of `scores.each`, which is `scores`.

You're outputting the `<li>` tags inside the `.each` block, and then when the `.each` is done, the value returned from `each` (`scores`) is being passed to `<%=` which echos it to the browser.

You need to be aware of when to use `<%` and `<%=`; in this case, you need `<%`.